# Neo4j how to create index with shell (bash shell)

Tags: bash, neo4j

I have written bash script to realize that downloading data from my
own database, then importing it into neo4j automatically.

now ***I also want the bash to create index automatically*** after
importing successfully, so that it can synchronized between my own
database and neo4j once a day automatically.

Comment: please specify the database and tag accordingly.

Comment: @piyushj  
you can consider my own databases as  any databases,but i can download data to csv file